# Creating quiz with flutter that has multi question and multi score

Tags: flutter

Trying to create a quiz affects multiple scores if someone chooses an answer. is it possible? so I just need to find out a way to

Ask Question A: are you happy?
Answers: Agree, don't agree, and other
if solution Agree is selected it will update multiple scores differently
Score1: 10 - Score2: 20 - Score:30 - Score:40 - Score: 50

```
   class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'funny',
      'answers': [
        {
          'text': 'Strongly Disagree', 
          'score_A': 100,
          'score_B': 0,
          'score_C': 0,
          'score_D': 100,
          'score_E': 0,
          'score': 100
        },
        {
          'text': 'Disagree',
          'score_A': 75,
          'score_B': 25,
          'score_C': 25,
          'score_D': 75,
          'score_E': 25,
          'score': 100
        },
        {
          'text': 'Neutral',
          'score_A': 50,
          'score_B': 50,
          'score_C': 50,
          'score_D': 50,
          'score_E': 50,
          'score': 100
        },
        {
          'text': 'Agree',
          'score_A': 25,
          'score_B': 75,
          'score_C': 75,
          'score_D': 25,
          'score_E': 75,
          'score': 100
        },
        {
          'text': 'Strongly Agree',
          'score_A': 0,
          'score_B': 100,
          'score_C': 100,
          'score_D': 0,
          'score_E': 100,
          'score': 100
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'I make friends easily',
      'answers': [
        {
          'text': 'Strongly Disagree',
          'score_A': 0,
          'score_B': 100,
          'score_C': 100,
          'score_D': 0,
          'score_E': 0,
          'score': 100
        },
        {
          'text': 'Disagree',
          'score_A': 25,
          'score_B': 75,
          'score_C': 75,
          'score_D': 25,
          'score_E': 25,
          'score': 100
        },
        {
          'text': 'Neutral',
          'score_A': 50,
          'score_B': 50,
          'score_C': 50,
          'score_D': 50,
          'score_E': 50,
          'score': 100
        },
        {
          'text': 'Agree',
          'score_A': 5,
          'score_B': 5,
          'score_C': 5,
          'score_D': 5,
          'score_E': 5,
          'score': 5
        },
        {
          'text': 'Strongly Agree',
          'score_A': 5,
          'score_B': 5,
          'score_C': 5,
          'score_D': 5,
          'score_E': 5,
          'score': 5
        }
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'I trust myself to drive',
      'answers': [
        {
          'text': 'Strongly Disagree',
          'score_A': 5,
          'score_B': 5,
          'score_C': 5,
          'score_D': 5,
          'score_E': 5,
          'score': 5
        },
        {
          'text': 'Disagree',
          'score_A': 5,
          'score_B': 5,
          'score_C': 5,
          'score_D': 5,
          'score_E': 5,
          'score': 5
        },
        {
          'text': 'Neutral',
          'score_A': 5,
          'score_B': 5,
          'score_C': 5,
          'score_D': 5,
          'score_E': 5,
          'score': 5
        },
        {
          'text': 'Agree',
          'score_A': 5,
          'score_B': 5,
          'score_C': 5,
          'score_D': 5,
          'score_E': 5,
          'score': 5
        },
        {
          'text': 'Strongly Agree',
          'score_A': 5,
          'score_B': 5,
          'score_C': 5,
          'score_D': 5,
          'score_E': 5,
          'score': 5
        }
      ],
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Actually, you need to share sample data and actual implementation of it

Comment: the error i am getting is type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'score_A'
.
  void _answeQuestion(int score, int score_A, int score_B, int score_C,
      int score_D, int score_E) {
    _totalScore += score;
    A_totalScore += score_A;
    B_totalScore += score_B;
    C_totalScore += score_C;
    D_totalScore += score_D;
    E_totalScore += score_E;

Comment: Sorry, If you include that part, that may help. you can just have here single data model and rest code is implementation, More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: what I am trying to achieve is if someone clicks on one of the answers it will record a score. but in this case, it's not one score. it will be multiple scores affected. which later on It will be calculated